# Python emails is not sending emails

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

I'm trying to send emails using the python emails library. It works perfectly on my local machine. But it doesn't work on the server. I have checked the response code and it is always 421. Both of the machines using the same version of python but my local machine runs on windows where my server is running on Linux.

I'm using the following code:

```
def send_reset_password_reset_code(email, reset_code):
    message = emails.html(html="<p>Hi!<br>Here is your reset code.<br>email: {}<br>password: {}".format(email, reset_code),
                   subject="Password Reset Notification.",
                   mail_from=('Admin', 'admin@****net.com'))
    r = message.send(to=email, smtp={'host': 'aspmx.l.google.com', 'timeout': 5})
    return r.status_code == 250
```

Comment: This one? https://pypi.org/project/emails/

Comment: @tripleee yes, this one. I'm sorry not to include the link.